# FMX - Two triggers in animations

Tags: delphi, animation, firemonkey

Is it possible to use two or more triggers in an FMX animation?

For example:

Apply the animation only when: IsFocused=true and IsMouseOver=false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course, you can do it at this way :

Just paste the following string on animation trigger property

`IsFocused=true;IsMouseOver=false`

Take a look here for more information :

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/FireMonkey_Animation_Effects